# How to Play Three.js FBX animation on mousewheel frame by frame?

Tags: three.js, blender

Hey I am loading a FBX animation through three.js, what I want is to play the animation on mousewheel scroll.

Something like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5027BSayqC4

Comment: Hey! Any pieces of code of what you've tried?

Comment: Hey I was referring for this example https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_fbx.html. I want to play the animation like in the video I posted. Animation should not autoplay.

Comment: Hey [prisoner849](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4045502/prisoner849) just now I tried on mouse wheel and I got the forward animation, can you tell me how to make it forward on scroll down and backward on scroll up.

Reference https://jsfiddle.net/baxshzrm/

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully done that below is the code:

```
function onMouseWheel( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    if(event.deltaY > 1){
      for ( var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i ++ ) {
        mixers[ i ].update( clock.getDelta() * 1 );
      }
    } else {
      for ( var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i ++ ) {
        mixers[ i ].update( clock.getDelta() * -1 );
      }
    }
}
```

Here is the working file https://jsfiddle.net/baxshzrm/1/